# Parse string using Regular expression

Tags: c#

i have this kind of string `File type:           Wireshark - pcapng`
so what i want is if my string start with `File type:` take and parse only `Wireshark - pcapng`

this is what i have try:

```
var myString = @":\s*(.*?)\s* ";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of REGEX, use [`string.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) method, something like:

```
if(str.StartsWith("File type:"))
   Console.WriteLine(str.Substring("File type:".Length));
```

You will get:

```
 Wireshark - pcapng
```

If you want to get rid of leading/trailing spaces from the resultant string then use [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) like:

```
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring("File type:".Length).Trim());
```

Or if you just want to get rid of leading spaces then use [string.TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx) like:

```
Console.WriteLine(str.Substring("File type:".Length).TrimStart(' '));
```

Comment: You should also remove the space after `:`.

Comment: received Wireshark - pcapng, with empty characters at the beginning

Comment: @user2214609, use `string.Trim`, check the latest answer

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just remove `File type:` from your string:

```
str = str.Replace("File type: ",string.Empty);
```

Or you can check if the string starts with `File type:` and remove that part using `string.Remove()`:

```
if(str.StartsWith("File type: "){
    str=str.Remove(11); //length of "File Type: "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
(?<=^File type: ).*$
```

so...

```
var match = Regex.Match("File type: Wireshark - pcapng", @"(?<=^File type: ).*$");
if(match.Success)
{
    var val = match.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```